# Align buttons next to input field - Twitter Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

You can see in my Demo that the buttons aren't aligned correctly :-(

Is it possible to:

1) have a space between the input field and the buttons &

2) have the buttons vertically aligned correctly?

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/xg69pkt0/

**Code:**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="concept" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="concept" name="concept">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default blue-bt pull-left" name="Continue" id="Continue"  align="top" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:10px">Find Address</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default blue-bt pull-left" name="Continue" id="Continue"  align="top" type="submit">Change</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/a3xnqy33/

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="concept" name="concept">
                        <div class="input-group-btn inup-group-addon">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">Find Address</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" name="Continue" id="Continue"  align="top" type="submit">Change</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

please see the modified fiddle

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to help. My only slight complaint is the width of the input field is tiny at Desktop level. Is there any way to fix this? :)

Comment: the width is  based on the width of buttons and the containers width? not sure what you are talking about.. the width is quite big in the fiddle i have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can check the following also. In your code you have not closed your divs properly.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Postcode</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="concept" name="concept">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default blue-bt" name="Continue" id="Continue" type="submit">Find Address</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default blue-bt" name="Continue" id="Continue" type="submit">Change</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```